# Atom Beautify Ruby with rubocop doens't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atom-editor, atom-beautify

I have Atom Beautify plugin installed in Atom and the rubocop gem installed in my app. Even after these steps the beautify don't work.

My rubocop location:

```
  $ which rubocop 
  /home/leonardo/.rbenv/shims/rubocop
```

In my config.cson i have the code:

```
...
    ruby:
      rubocop_path: "/home/leonardo/.rbenv/shims/rubocop"
...
```

When I try using Beatify(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) this return the error:

```
Error: rbenv: rubocop: command not found
The `rubocop' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.3
    at /home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/executable.coffee:182:23
    at tryCatcher (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (/home/leonardo/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Comment: Is there a chance that you switched to ruby version without rubocop gem installed?

Comment: It will give a lot of work. 
The project is already advanced. The problem can be this?

Comment: I mean error message says that `rubocop` command exists in ruby 2.4.3 but if you switched to a project with different ruby version you might need to install `rubycop` for that

Comment: But my project is in the version 2.4.3 of ruby and rubocop is installed on it :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem. My project was on version 2.2.2 and rubocop gem was installed on this version.

Atom was running `atom-beautify`, but using the global `rbenv` version (in my case was 2.4.0) and that was causing the error. So the solution was:

```
$ cd ~
$ rbenv version
2.4.0
$ gem install rubocop
```

Then restart Atom, run `atom-beautify` and everything should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem the other day. I'm using Ruby 2.7.4 and to get the path for Atom Beautify to use I used `rbenv which rubocop` instead of `which rubocop`.

```
$ rbenv which rubocop
/Users/YourUsername/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/rubocop
```

Afterwards, copy and paste the above path to Atom Beautify's settings --> Executables --> Rubocop --> Binary/Script Path text field. And then restart Atom.